# One upstream event with multiple items, how to set up spring integration pipeline transaction-wise

Tags: java, spring, architecture, transactions, spring-integration

Let's imagine the situation where you have incoming upstream message which contains multiple items. Each item contains the information which participates in the business logic implemented as part of the pipeline.

Difficulties I can see:
Message has to be split & converted into multiple internal events, those are processed further and if one of them fails, then all internal events should be rolled back
If we had one upstream message = 1 item, it would be much easier

How should one cater for such situation from architecture point of view?
What is the best pattern to employ here?
How should one set up transactions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question isn't clear and that `transaction` word is used for different subjects...

Anyway let me guess what you want.

If you are going (and can) to roll back part of the business request, you should just ensure global XA transaction for all of them and do all splitted sub-tasks in the same thread. Because only this let you keep and track transaction and roll backs afterwards, if that.

If you can't deal with XA and single thread, than you should take a look to some solutions like compensation transaction or acknowledge with claim-checks.

But that is already outside of Spring Integration scope.

Comment: Hi Artem, I have updated my question.
The thing I want to achieve is to consume upstream message, chunk it up into multiple internal events and if any of those internal events fails for any reason, then roll back

Is using of global XA transactions still applicable? Which example would you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Right, it is. But you still have to ensure everything in one thread. Otherwise no tx boundaries and no auto roll back.

Comment: So, should I combine Atomikos with Spring integration flow somehow (e.g. by configuring JTA tx manager)? 
We use tomcat for dev purposes and weblogic in prod

Comment: Well, actually it depends of your transactional resource. Maybe there would be enough to use simple 1PC TxManager, or even SI `PseudoTransactionManager`. OTOH take a look into `ChainedTransactionManager` instead of monolith XA one.